# Is useInsertionEffect equals to useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

I've create a piece of program in React using useInsertionEffect() hook in this manner:

```
import { useState, useInsertionEffect, useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const ref = useRef(null)

  useInsertionEffect(() => {
    document.title = `Counter: ${count}`;    
    if (count >= 5)
      try {
        ref.current.parentNode.removeChild(ref.current)
      } catch (e) { }
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button ref={ref}>will be removed</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>press me</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It works: any time I click in "press me" button the `count` var is updated and document title too. Documentation says: "useInsertionEffect allows inserting elements into the DOM before any layout effects fire." but I see this code update counter after each click. And... "You can’t update state from inside useInsertionEffect." But I am updating document title...

For example I expected that useInsertionEffect should be called just at the beginning of the page loading/rendering.